# Conservation of energy with metastable pure states and doubts about energy-time uncertainty relation

Tags: energy-conservation, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, half-life

Experimentally we know there are [metastable states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metastability#Quantum_mechanics) in nuclear physics and molecular physics. For example, the isotope Tantalum-180m ${}^{180m}\text{Ta}$ is long-lived metastable excited state, with a half-life calculated to be least $4.5\cdot 10^{16}$ years (3 million times the current age of the universe). In principle, we can construct a superposition of the ground state ${}^{180}\text{Ta}$ and the metastable state:

$$|\psi_0\rangle = \cos\alpha\ |{}^{180}\text{Ta}\rangle + e^{i\beta}\sin\alpha\ |{}^{180m}\text{Ta}\rangle $$

whose evolution will be:

$$|\psi_t\rangle = e^{-iE_0t/\hbar}\cos\alpha\ |{}^{180}\text{Ta}\rangle + e^{-i(E_mt/\hbar\ - \ \beta)}\sin\alpha\ \ |{}^{180m}\text{Ta}\rangle $$

Clearly, the energy does not have a defined value, however, the average value of the energy is constant:

$$\langle E \rangle_t = \langle \psi_t|\hat{H}|\psi_t\rangle = E_0\cos^2\alpha + E_m\sin^2\alpha$$

being $E_0$ the energy of the ground state, and $E_m$ the energy of the metastable state. Computing standard deviation in the energy:

$$\Delta_\psi E = \langle\hat{H}^2\rangle_\psi - \langle\hat{H}\rangle^2_\psi = \cos\alpha\sin\alpha\ |E_m-E_0|$$

we see that it is also constant. Then the [energy-time uncertainty relation](https://www.classe.cornell.edu/%7Ehoff/LECTURES/05S_316/05_04_06.pdf) $\Delta_\psi E \cdot\Delta_\psi t \ge \hbar/2$ suggest that the necessary time for observing a transition is given by:

$$\Delta_\psi t \ge \frac{\hbar}{2\Delta_\psi E} = \frac{\hbar}{2|E_m-E_0|\sin\alpha\cos\alpha}$$

My questions are:

1. Is correct to affirm that the energy is conserved in this kind of superpositions because $\text{d}\langle E \rangle_t/\text{d}t = 0$?
2. Is the estimate $\hbar/(2|E_m-E_0|) \approx 4.5\cdot 10^{16}$ years, right?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, in general when you have a time independent Hamiltonian, you’ll always have conservation of energy $\langle H\rangle =cst$ for any initial state.
2. You can’t deduce the half-life of a metastable state just by its energy, they are a priori unrelated quantities. In general, you are modeling nuclear decay by a perfect two state system which isn’t realistic precisely because it cannot reproduce the decay effect.

The reason behind this inconsistency is that metastable states are not energy eigenstates. Formally, a metastable state can be modeled by introducing an imaginary part to its energy which will give the expected exponential decay. In your case, you should do the substitution:
$$
E_m\to E_m-i\frac{\Gamma}{2}
$$
with $\Gamma$ the decay rate related to the half-life $\tau$ by $\Gamma \tau=\ln 2$.

You can do it rigorously using density matrices or Green’s functions for example. The time-energy uncertainty is applied to the exponential decay, which now has a broad spectrum (Lorentzian) whose bandwidth is related to the lifetime and the peak located at the energy of the state.

Note that it makes sense to talk about a metastable state only when the decay rate is sufficiently small compared to the energy or graphically the width sufficiently small to resolve the peak at the energy.

Hope this helps.